# List particular function calls in outline of eclipse

Tags: eclipse-cdt

In my C-code I repeatedly use a function from an external library:

```
XCALL("Blabla");
...
XCALL_END("Blabla");
```

It would be very helpful to be able to put each XCALL call into the outline view for better code querying. However, I could not find an easy solution for this. Also, installed Xtext in hope it was easy to configure. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any customization point open by CDT for modifying the behavior of the Outline view so I think you would have to get the CDT sources and build your customized version if you want to do that - or maybe see if they would be interested in you making this behavior customizable via extensions. In any case, this would represent quite a lot of work.